# Fill selection of 3D Array (paperio remake)

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, flood-fill

I'm doing a simple paper.io remake, but I don't have any idea how can I implement flood fill algorithm.

I have an 30x30 array which stores cell object (it has info about cell owner/tail owner). When player gets back to his own territory, his tail changes to owned cells, but how to fill selected space (like on image). [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmLIS.png)